# How can I reset a toggle that is active when an href is clicked on?

Tags: javascript

You could visit my website at owenngimli.com

If you inspect it in mobile size, there should be a responsive navbar which covers the whole page. The thing is, when i press on 'contact', it should then close the navbar and scroll the page down to the contact section.

I'm using JavaScript to toggle the burger and the navbar. The syntax is as such:

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links-mobile");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links-mobile li");

  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");

    // Animate Links

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
          index / 7 + 0.3
        }s`;
      }
    });

    // Burger Animation

    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
  });
};

navSlide();
```

So far, I tried adding another function which removes the `nav-active` class. However, this causes the burger to work wrongly. The function I tried adding was an onclick function with syntax as such:

```
const testFunc = () => {
   const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links-mobile");

   nav.classList.remove("nav-active");
 };
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Owenn. When asking for help it is best to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This helps others *help you*. It also gives yourself the opportunity to find flaws with your current implementation. Right now you've pasted some JS, so if anyone wants to try and help, they will have to inspect the source on your website and try to recreate what is going. The best way to get quality answers to make it easy to help you. Right now, that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a jQuery function that gets triggered when contact button is clicked.

`$('#foo').trigger('click');`

where foo is the id of the close button on the side nav.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the nav on link click also.

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links-mobile");
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links-mobile li");
  
    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
      nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
  
      // Animate Links
  
      navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
          link.style.animation = "";
        } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
            index / 7 + 0.3
          }s`;
        }
      });
  
      // Burger Animation
  
      burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
    });

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => { link.addEventListener('click', nav.classList.toggle('nav-active') )});
  };
  
  navSlide();
```